# How to determine the number of columns in a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have A CSV file that at the beginning has 2 columns, and in some row, there are 4 columns. I want to use only the 2 columns and ignore the others.

my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path,header=None,nrows=NUM_OF_CONF_ROWS,skiprows=2)
```

the error:

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 17, saw 4

example of the data:

```
 1,2
 2,4
 ...
 1,2,3,4
 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `usecols` to indicate which columns you want to use :

```
df = pd.read_csv(path,header=None,nrows=NUM_OF_CONF_ROWS,skiprows=2, usecols = [0 1])
```

Comment: Thanks! if the columns don't have headers, how can I use it?

Comment: I tried on a csv file having two columns used in the first two lines then three with no header. And it seems like the option `usecols` doesn't require a header, it works as a positionnal argument. What kind of error do you have when you run the code ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as in the beginning you only have 2 columns and becomes 4 columns all in all because of the existence of not empty values in that column on higher indexes. Which means that your csv file has indeed 4 columns to start.

If you just need the first 2 columns, you can 'drop' the rest using `df.columns.isin()` method like:

```
df = df.loc[df.columns.isin('place column names or index in a list and put it here')]
```

And you'll get the 2 columns you wanted.

Hope this helps :))

Comment: Read your file as basic `df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', header = 0)` then use the code above to drop whichever columns you don't want to include.